# Got a 08003 when DB2 Calls in sourced Code

Tags: bash, db2

I hope this post is better to understand:
I use the bash db2 function to create a sessions and after this i want to execute some code. When i do it in a sourced Script i get a 08003.
dbconnect.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
{
db2 -x +c < Connectionstring  # RC is 0
db2 -x +c "Select * from Table" # RC is 4, erros say 08003
}
```

main.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
. ./dbconnect.sh
```

change dbconnect to following code is not helping:
dbconnect.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
db2 -x +c < Connectionstring  # RC is 0
db2 -x +c "Select * from Table" # RC is 4, erros say 08003
```

but putting all in one file works perfekt:

```
#!/bin/bash
db2 -x +c < Connectionstring  
db2 -x +c "Select * from Table"
```

Any Ideas?

The Bashversion:
4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnx)

Linux Version:
SUSE LINUX Enterprise Server 12 SP3

Comment: With bash, the db2 clp will not inherit the explicit connection made by a parent  for any subshells by default.  Use instead ksh93 which does not have this problem.

Comment: But the both db2 comands are inside the same Script, and if i know correctly the source function is not opening a second shell as i know.... Sadly i can't change the shell...

Comment: but i don't acces it from the caller... i acces it only in the dbconnect.sh and there it's not working

Comment: echo ${BASH_VERSION} didn't gave me any output, so i used `bash --version` i execute the real db2

Comment: I observe that on my bash version 5.0.17(1), that your sample code does not show the behaviour you report, and running ./main.sh runs the ./dbconnect.sh, and it reports the result of the queries successfully, and the command `db2level` reports v11.5.6.

Comment: yeah bei db2level reports v11.1.4.4 so yeah it's lower

Comment: I also verified that on v11.1.4.6, your example code does not exhibit your symptom when run by bash `5.0.17(1)`, so I conclude your version of bash needs upgrading. Or in your scripts ,use `#!/bin/ksh93`  if installed.

Comment: Thx a lot for the effort!!! i will try out this... sadly my codebase ist not working out of box withg ksh93 buts installed

Comment: So it took some time but now i checked it with BASH 5.1 in our environment. It works perfectly. So thank you for you help!